# Firebase rules change

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to stop reading data from firebase by using rules change. Here is the rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read,  write;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to disallow all. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
allow read, write;
```

to this:

```
allow read, write: if false;
```